# Memory full and other problems parsing large size xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have an XML trace file and the size of this file is about 350 Mb. when I use the following code one time it produces the memory full problem and the other time it produces an error about could not parse the file. what should I do for parsing this huge file?do I use a different method for parsing?

```
    root = ET.parse('E:/software/jm_16.1/bin/tracefile.xml').getroot()
    lst = root.findall('AVCTrace/Picture/SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock')
    for item in lst:
        print (item.get('QP_Y'))

I also produce a smaller file and based on the above file and the variable `lst` is empty!!. do you know what is the problem?
my XML trace file is as follows:

    I also need to extract X tag and Y tag in Macroblock. for this I used <MacroBlock num="8158">
                <SubMacroBlock num="0">
                    <Type>1</Type>
                    <TypeString>B_L0_8x8</TypeString>
                    <MotionVector list="0">
                        <RefIdx>0</RefIdx>
                        <Difference>
                            <X>-1</X>
                            <Y>-2</Y>
                        </Difference>
                        <Absolute>
                            <X>-4</X>
                            <Y>-6</Y>
                        </Absolute>
                    </MotionVector>
                </SubMacroBlock>
```

Comment: Use [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/)

Comment: See also : https://www.trivialproblems.com/posts/incremental-xml-parsing-with-python/

Comment: Thank you. using ET I could pars it but when I use item.get('QP_Y') it gets nothing and all of them is None. how can I achieve the value of QP_Y? for example in the above example is 28.

Comment: lst is a list with 979200 elemnt.

Comment: @JonSG your comment is about my last question about finding QP_Y value?

Comment: would you please tell me how can I extract the value of QP_Y?

Comment: this is part of the above problem. after solving the first problem I need to find the value of QP_Y.

Comment: that means I have to ask another question?

Comment: @david A different user suggested there were already lots of questions like this and posted a link to stack overflow search. That link though produced 0 search results. I was just giving them a heads up.  Your question seems fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


root = ET.parse('68071609.xml').getroot()
print(root.tag)  # Picture
elems = root.findall('SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/QP_Y')
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)  # 28
```

The root of your tree is already `Picture`, so you should not search for a `Picture/...` inside it.
You can search all the nodes named `QP_Y` directly by adding it to your search path.

If you prefer to iterate over the macro blocks instead, and have their QP_Y :

```py
elems = root.findall('SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock')
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.attrib)  # {'num': '0'}
    qp_y = next(child for child in elem if child.tag == "QP_Y").text  # will throw StopIteration if missing
    print(qp_y)  # 28
```

Comment: is it a way to put all QP_Y value into an array without using for loop to access each item?

Comment: `list(qpy_node.text for qpy_node in root.findall('SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/QP_Y'))`

Comment: I used your new comment above but when I want to achieve the TypeString in Macroblock it returns just one element while I have about 902000 element
tsMB=list(qpy_node.text for qpy_node in root.findall('Picture/SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/TypeString'))

Comment: @david: You have already accepted the answer. If you have additional concerns, please ask a new question. You have also edited the question substantially after this answer was posted. Don't do that.

Comment: the question I asked here is about the answer that is posted and I accepted that, so when for some examples it does not work, it means it has a problem and it should be solve here.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer if you are not happy with it? Move on, ask a new question. Do not pile on comments to an accepted answer.